# repo tool constructing invalid project urls

Tags: android-source, repo

I have a repo manifest that declares a remote with an `https` fetch url. Given the number of projects in the AOSP manifest, typing a username/password for every project being synced is going to take days.
I've forked the manifest repo, and copied this file as a new file, changing the remote's fetch url from `<remote fetch="https://git.githost.org/foo/bar" name="fubar" review="githost.org"/>` to `<remote fetch="git@git.githost.org:foo/bar" name="fubar" review="githost.org"/>`.

Before you ask:

- Yes, I've successfully cloned both `https://git.githost.org/foo/bar/some-repo.git` and `git@git.githost.org:foo/bar/some-repo.git` so I know that the URIs are valid and that I have access to them.
- Yes I've updated my `repo init` command to use my forked repo and `-m` to the new manifest

BUT, when I run `repo init ...` and then `repo sync`, repo complains that the repo doesn't exists or that I don't have access to it.

I'd include the manifests, but they're not mine, they're not publicly available, and I don't want to get fired or sued.

Beofre changing the fetch url I made sure my fork of the repo was sane by running `repo init -u ...` and `repo sync` so the *only change* here is the fetch url of the remote.

**UPDATE 1**

I gave repo a while longer to run and it's printing out URLs and these urls look real messed up. Let's say the original menifest repo was `git@git.githost.org:foo/bar/platform/manifest.git` and I forked it to my personal repo at `ssh://git@myrepo.com/fubar/manifest.git`. Considering the project `platform/external/apache-commons-compress`, instead of trying to fetch `git@git.githost.org:foo/bar/platform/external/apache-commons-compress.git` it's trying to get `ssh://git@myrepo.com/fubar/git@git.githost.org:foo/bar/platform/external/apache-commons-compress`.

**UPDATE 2**

After some poking around, it looks like the `repo init` is not corrently intializing the repos. For example inside `.repo/projects/art.git/config`, I have the following snippet:

```
[remote "fubar"]
    url = ssh://git@myrepo.com/fubar/git@git.githost.org:foo/bar/art
```

This should be

```
[remote "fubar"]
    url = git@git.githost.org:foo/bar/art
```

**UPDATE 3**

I fixed the `art` repo and ran `repo sync` again, hoping that this time the one repo that I fixed would sync, but the config was overwritten.

**UPDATE 4**
Here are abbreviated versions of the manifests:

Before (`https`)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest>
  <remote fetch="https://git.githost.org/foo/bar" name="fubar" review="githost.org"/>
  <default remote="fubar" revision="blah"/>
  <project groups="g1,g2" name="device/generic/art" revision="abcdef1234567890abcdef" upstream="refs/heads/blah"/>
</manifest>
```

After (`git`)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest>
  <remote fetch="git@git.githost.org:foo/bar" name="fubar" review="githost.org"/>
  <default remote="fubar" revision="blah"/>
  <project groups="g1,g2" name="device/generic/art" revision="abcdef1234567890abcdef" upstream="refs/heads/blah"/>
</manifest>
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Why is `repo sync` combining the fetch url of the repos with the origin url of the manifest? Should I pass something extra to `repo init`?

Comment: Can you show what your <project> elements look like? And what do the urls in the config look like before changing anything?

Comment: @TeemuRisikko Here's the fetch url from the config of the same `art` project: `https://git.githost.org/foo/bar/art`
I will update the question with `project` elements (which I have not touched).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to clone from the original https URLs, and you are trying these because you are not able to repo init and sync with https, consider using .netrc file. You can create a .netrc file in your home directory with 600 permissions with the below content.

```
machine <host>  login <username>  password <password>
```

Comment: I am using `~/.netrc` right now, but I'm wondering what's causing those incorrect fetch URLs